# How to extract the output of model?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, prediction

I have to submit my predictions (each of them is one of 2289 classes!). But, I don't know how to do this. Help me!!

Model looks like this
:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), input_shape=(32,64,1), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2000, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(2289, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

and i used fit function

```
history = model.fit(trainimage,trainlabel, validation_data=(validimage,validlabel), epochs=10, batch_size=200)
```

What I wanna know is how to extract the predictions of given test images

```
# Indexing of predictions
argpreds = np.argmax(history)

# Load label dictionary
with open('./drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/CoE202_KakaoArena/y_vocab.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    y_dict = pickle.load(f)

# Inverse label dictionary
inv_y_dict = dict((y,x) for x,y in y_dict.items())
submissions = [inv_y_dict[argpred] for argpred in argpreds]

# Write the results to 'submissions.csv'
f = open('./drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/CoE202_KakaoArena/submissions.csv', 'w')
for i, j in zip(pids, submissions):
    line = '{},{}\n'.format(i,j)
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

This is a modification of my TA's code. But I got an error "TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable"

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score -1):

Generally the error object is not iterable occurs when you are using a variable like a list. So its only single dimensional data type like an int mot a list.